# How to set a featured image from a post image url?

Tags: wordpress

I'm using a plugin called Movie Poster which collects information about a movie and creates an automated post for my review site. This automated post displays a poster image of the movie via a URL source. The theme that I'm using is Arras Project AR2. How can I make this image URL also be the featured image of that post? Thank you for your time and answers.

Comment: Does the poster is your first image in the post? if so, use one of the plugins I gave in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/auto-post-thumbnail/

and this :

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/easy-add-thumbnail/

good luck

Comment: Yes, the poster is the first image in the post but it is not uploaded on the post, it is just the URL displaying the image.  Would these plugins still work with that?

Comment: can you post the part of the code after execution of the page? I mean the part of the code that includes this URL. It will be better if you add it as an edit in your post so that more poeple from SO helps you

Comment: <img src="{$poster}" height="325" width="225" border="0" alt="" /> Where {$poster} is the url.

Comment: So in in my consideration, on of the plugins above will work since you have the img tag in your code. the src attribute should always contain an URL so that the image shows. good luck

Comment: Please come back here and feedback if my answer is fitting with your situation.